# SQL Server DATEDIFF Computed Column Between Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I currently have a table similar to this -

```
RecordTime                    Running     Fault
-----------------------------------------------
2016-09-15 11:32:01.00        0           202
2016-09-15 11:32:08.00        1           202
2016-09-15 11:39:31.00        0           21
2016-09-15 11:40:07.00        1           4
2016-09-15 11:42:11.00        0           21
2016-09-15 11:42:39.00        1           45
```

I then wanted to calculate the time difference between the RecordTimes for each record.  For this I am using the following -

```
WITH    rows AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RecordTime) AS rn
        FROM    dbo.Table1
        )
SELECT  DATEDIFF(second, mc.RecordTime, mp.RecordTime)
FROM    rows mc
JOIN    rows mp
ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
```

Which returns -

```
(No column name)
----------------
7
443
36
124
28
303
```

What I actually want to do, though, is create a computed column in the original table that gives me these values.  Is this possible?

I thought that I might be able to convert the query into a UDF and then reference that in the column, but I'm not very experienced with that kind of work.

---edit---

Final result should be -

```
RecordTime                    Running     Fault     Diff
--------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-15 11:32:01.00        0           202       7
2016-09-15 11:32:08.00        1           202       443
2016-09-15 11:39:31.00        0           21        36
2016-09-15 11:40:07.00        1           4         124
2016-09-15 11:42:11.00        0           21        28
2016-09-15 11:42:39.00        1           45        303
```

Comment: show your final result should be..

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: 2012...sorry, should have said

Comment: It will effect the performance, better to get it  on the fly

Comment: on the fly?  How do you mean?  Also, sorry for delay, I'm working through the answers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you to use a view for this purpose:

```
CREATE VIEW Table1_vw 
AS
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RecordTime) AS rn
    FROM    dbo.Table1
)
SELECT  mc.RecordTime,
        mc.Running,
        mc.Fault,
        DATEDIFF(second, mc.RecordTime, mp.RecordTime) Diff
FROM cte mc
LEFT JOIN cte mp
ON mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
```

Since you are using **SQL Server 2012** you can use [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) function:

```
CREATE VIEW Table1_vw 
AS
SELECT  RecordTime,
        Running,
        Fault,
        DATEDIFF(second,RecordTime,LEAD(RecordTime,1,NULL) OVER (ORDER BY RecordTime ASC) ) as Diff
FROM Table1
GO
```

Comment: Hey @gofr1, This is a very clear answer (and works!).  But could you explain why it is better to create the view?  Is it more efficient than a UDF and calculated column?

Comment: @swe Well, it is not that new :) Get some time to read articles and blogs like ([SQL authority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/), [SQLServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/), etc) and reading answers/questions here on SO as well!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @gofr1.  I'll have start thinking more about using views rather than adding computed columns. It's certainly easier to write at least.

Comment: @Jamsandwich Sorry for delay in comments. From my experience using UDF in computed columns (or even inside the views) may cause great performance issues. But if you table will not grow dramatically and insert/update rate will not be that big - you can use UDF without any problems.

Comment: @gofr1 No bother.  My tables are small for now, but they'll likely grow as time goes on.  I'm inserting/updating every 10 mins for each table.  Don't know how that compares to the norm, but I'll go with views just to be on the safe side.  It also sounds like a useful way to think about the operations, especially since it appears to be easier to code!

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetTimeDiff (@time datetime)
RETURNS INT 
AS BEGIN
    declare @t1 datetime 

    DECLARE @Ret int

    SELECT @t1 = RecordTime 
    FROM (
        SELECT  RecordTime, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RecordTime DESC) AS rn
        FROM Table1
        WHERE RecordTime < @time
    ) i
    WHERE i.rn = 1

    SELECT @Ret = DATEDIFF(second, @t1, @time)
    RETURN @Ret
END
GO

ALTER TABLE Table1
ADD TimeDiff AS dbo.GetTimeDiff(RecordTime) 
GO
```

You need to add logic to the function to handle NULL @t1 etc.

Update to make it work with the next row:

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RecordTime ASC) AS rn
        FROM Table1
        WHERE RecordTime > @time
```

And this to make all values positive rather than negative:

```
SELECT @Ret = ABS(DATEDIFF(second, @t1, @time))
```

Comment: I get a couple of errors with this.  On line 12 - "Select statements within function cannot return data to a client" & "Last statement in a function must be a return statement".

Comment: Hey artm.  This function now works.  But the TimeDiff appears offset by 1 row.  So the first row shows nulls and then it's calculating difference from previous row.  Is it possible to calculate difference from next row?

Comment: Awesome.  That works.  Was getting negative values until until I added ABS function to the final Select.  What's your opinion on using this over a view as suggested by Gofr1?

Comment: @Jamsandwich I was just trying to answer the computed column part of the question but I think Gofr1 's answer (+1) is a better option.

Comment: OK, great.  I'll go with the view then.  +1 though, for showing me how this can be done as a computed column.  It's great to see an example of a UDF that I can relate my own data to.

Comment: @Jamsandwich I can relate to that, no worries, happy to help.