# sqlalchemy column computing difference between rows

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

Can you help me to solve following problem?
i have table in sqlalchemy ORM (Python)

```
    class Item(Base):
       __tablename__='items'
       id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
       title = Column(String)

    class Stat(Base):
       __tablename__='stats'
       id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
       item_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('items.id'))
       price = Column(Float)
       date = column(Date)
```

I want to get column "diff" computing price difference between rows of current and former dates of Stat table. How can i implement it?

I took a look at similar questions ([SQL Server DATEDIFF Computed Column Between Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529045/sql-server-datediff-computed-column-between-rows), [Compare difference between two columns in SQLAlchemy ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505946/compare-difference-between-two-columns-in-sqlalchemy-orm)). So which way do you think is more suitable? Creating a view, events or something else?

Comment: Depending on your DBMS window functions may be an option.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä, can you please be more specific?)